# Can't modify ETCD manifest for Kubernetes static pod

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I'd like to modify etcd pod to listening 0.0.0.0(or host machine IP) instead of 127.0.0.1.

I'm working on a migration from a single master to multi-master kubernetes cluster, but I faced with an issue that after I modified /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml with correct settings and restart kubelet and even docker daemons, etcd still working on 127.0.0.1.

Inside docker container I'm steel seeing that etcd started with --listen-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379 instead of host IP

**cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: etcd
    tier: control-plane
  name: etcd
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - etcd
    - --advertise-client-urls=https://192.168.22.9:2379
    - --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt
    - --client-cert-auth=true
    - --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
    - --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://192.168.22.9:2380
    - --initial-cluster=test-master-01=https://192.168.22.9:2380
    - --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
    - --listen-client-urls=https://192.168.22.9:2379
    - --listen-peer-urls=https://192.168.22.9:2380
    - --name=test-master-01
    - --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt
    - --peer-client-cert-auth=true
    - --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key
    - --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --snapshot-count=10000
    - --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    image: k8s.gcr.io/etcd-amd64:3.2.18
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -ec
        - ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://[192.168.22.9]:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
          --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
          get foo
      failureThreshold: 8
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: etcd
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/lib/etcd
      name: etcd-data
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
      name: etcd-certs
  hostNetwork: true
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/etcd
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etcd-data
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etcd-certs
status: {}
```

**[root@test-master-01 centos]# kubectl -n kube-system get po etcd-test-master-01 -o yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/config.hash: c3eef2d48a776483adc00311df8cb940
    kubernetes.io/config.mirror: c3eef2d48a776483adc00311df8cb940
    kubernetes.io/config.seen: 2019-05-24T13:50:06.335448715Z
    kubernetes.io/config.source: file
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: 2019-05-24T14:08:14Z
  labels:
    component: etcd
    tier: control-plane
  name: etcd-test-master-01
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "6288"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/etcd-test-master-01
  uid: 5efadb1c-7e2d-11e9-adb7-fa163e267af4
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - etcd
    - --advertise-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt
    - --client-cert-auth=true
    - --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
    - --initial-advertise-peer-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2380
    - --initial-cluster=test-master-01=https://127.0.0.1:2380
    - --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
    - --listen-client-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --listen-peer-urls=https://127.0.0.1:2380
    - --name=test-master-01
    - --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt
    - --peer-client-cert-auth=true
    - --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key
    - --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --snapshot-count=10000
    - --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    image: k8s.gcr.io/etcd-amd64:3.2.18
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -ec
        - ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=https://[127.0.0.1]:2379 --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
          --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
          get foo
```

Comment: please post the manifest you're using

Comment: Hi, @jaxxstorm Added etcd.yaml manifest content in post above and fragment of running pod yaml

Comment: The strange thing that when I did this procedure manually last time all worked fine and I succesfully joined etcd members to cluster. But now I can't telnet etcd using host IP

Comment: did you kill the pod after you made the changes?

Comment: Yep, I deleted pod and docker container as well, restarted docker and kubelet daemons, even restarted master node, but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewed my automation scripts step by step and found that I've performed a backup of etcd yaml in the same folder with .bak extension. Looks like kubelet daemon uploads all the files inside the manifests folder and despite the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

First check your kubelet option `--pod-manifest-path`, put your correct yaml in this path.

To make sure `etcd` pod has been deleted, move yaml file out of `pod-manifest-path`, wait this pod has been deleted by `docker ps -a`. Then put your correct yaml file into `pod-manifest-path`.

Comment: Hi @menya, I've even change ```--pod-manifest-path``` to non-existing and wait until etcd docker container will be killed, and then change path back correct, but new docker container still the same